# Edit user input from form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently i'm using form_for read read a text_field called :comment, after the user submit it goes to the controller as such:

```
  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
    if @entry.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:comment)
    end
```

my question is whether I can search inside :comment (string) for a substring "test", when submitting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access what was submitted in the comment text field with `params[:entry][:comment]`, so you should be able to compare it to the value you want with `params[:entry][:comment].include?("test")`